# How to store stringbuffer into string array?

Tags: java, arrays, sqlite, android-listview, stringbuffer

Hi i am reading sqlite db data and store into string buffer. I want to display it in the list view in android. i am facing little problem. please help me to solve this issue.

```
String studentno=cursor.getString(1);
String date=cursor.getString(2);
buffer.append("student: "+studentno+"  Time:"+date+"\n");
String data=buffer.toString();
Log.d("student: "+studentno+"  Time:"+date);
```

the output is:`student: 1234  Time:12:13
    student: 1234  Time:12:14
    student: 1234  Time:12:15`

I want to store string buffer like this 
`values[0]=student: 1234  Time:12:13
values[1]=student: 1234  Time:12:14
values[2]=student: 1234  Time:12:15`

i tried below coding but its not working.

```
String[] values = data.split("");
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
list.add(values[i]);
}
```

is there any way to do this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be adding the data into the buffer with new line delimiter at the end. Splitting them should look like this: `data.split("\n");`

This does not seem like a good idea, however. Mainly because you can have a very large data set and split is an expensive operation.

Why not create an `ArrayList<String>` and call `list.add("student: " + studentno + " Time: " + date)` or some other more efficient structure?

Code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String studentno=cursor.getString(1);
String date=cursor.getString(2);
list.add("student: " + studentno + " Time: " + date);
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. If you want to store the data in an array, don't store it in a `StringBuffer` in the first place. Store it directly in the array.

You must have some loop in which you read the data :

```
String[] arr = new String [...];
int count = 0;
while (cursor.next() && count < arr.length) {
    String studentno=cursor.getString(1);
    String date=cursor.getString(2);
    arr[count] = "student: "+studentno+"  Time:"+date+"\n";
    count++;
}
```

Comment: How can you explain me in detail. I used data.split("\n"); its working now Eran.

Comment: its working Eran. but i cant know the string array size. we cant give predefine size.we dont know how many data will come from db. how can i give dynamic size. if i am wrong, pls correct me.

Comment: @subramaniam In that case, you can add the data to an ArrayList (whose capacity is dynamic) and then convert to an array with the toArray method.

Comment: @Eran i have same problem can u solve it plz.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948014/how-to-convert-single-string-to-jsonarray-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace your split call with this:

```
String[] values = data.split("\n");
```