# How to insert data into MySQL Server using ArrayAdapter (Java)?

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am new in android development, I want to insert call log details in MySQL database, here I have created simple `ArrayAdapter` that's not getting set in listview and second thing is, how to insert data in MySQL server.

Here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    getCallDetails();
}
private void getCallDetails()
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, strOrder);
    int number1 = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type1 = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int duration1 = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Log :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        final String number = managedCursor.getString(number1);
        final String type2 = managedCursor.getString(type1);
        final String date = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
        java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date(Long.valueOf(date));
        final String duration = managedCursor.getString(duration1);
        String type = null;
        final String fDate = date1.toString();
        int callcode = Integer.parseInt(type2);
        switch (callcode)
        {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                type = "Outgoing";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                type = "Incoming";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                type = "Missed";
                break;
        }
        List<DataBean> DataBeanList = new  ArrayList<DataBean>();
        DataBean dataBean = new DataBean(number, type, fDate, duration);
        DataBeanList.add(dataBean);
        Log.d("tag", DataBeanList.toString());
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
   }
 }
```

Here is my php script.........

```
 <?php 
 //Importing our db connection script
 require_once('connect.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
//Getting values
$number = $_POST['number'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

//Creating an sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO call_detail (number,duration,type,time) VALUES   ('$number','$duration','$type','$time')";

    //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Entry Added Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Add Entry';
    }

//Closing the database 
mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

Comment: so basically you want to insert them into mysql tables? Have you written the scripts in php to get the data from java?

Comment: yes i have written the scripts in php.......@helldawg

Comment: right so you just want a way to actually send the data from android to the php file and then it will insert them to mysql. That can be achieved with httpUrlConnection and make POST requests

Comment: yes i know but how to insert data using arrayadapter......

Comment: i just add my php file show that.........

Comment: i dont think arrayadapter is necessary in this step...i will give you a code snippet to see

Comment: first time i have been upload single string in MySQL server. but server more load and my server is suspend. so give me some suggestion what i do.....

Answer (score 1):

Well i am using this method to upload data from Android to MySQL Database. First of all you need an `AsyncTask` to communicate with the .php file and send the data. So i would suggest to try this:

```
public class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage("Data Processing");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                setupDataToDB();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                outputStreamWriter.write(dataToWrite.toString());
                Log.e("Data To Write", dataToWrite.toString());
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("Response Code ", String.valueOf(responseCode));
                if (responseCode == 200){
                   InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                   StringBuilder jsonResult = inputStreamToString(inputStream, YourActivity.this);
                   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.toString());
                   Log.e("Data From JSON", jsonResponse.toString());
                   return true;
                }else{
                    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
                    Log.e("ERROR STREAM", inputStream.toString());
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return false;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (aVoid){
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Data Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                YourActivity.this.finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "There was a problemm sending the data. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private void setupDataToDB() {
        JSONObject dataToWrite = new JSONObject();
        try {
            dataToWrite.put("number", numberStringFromJava);
            dataToWrite.put("duration", durationStringFromJava);
            dataToWrite.put("type", typeStringFromJava);
            dataToWrite.put("time", timeStringFromJava);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then your InputStreamToString method:

```
public StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is, Activity activity) {
        String rLine;
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            activity.finish();
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

And this should insert the data if everything is correct. You have to execute it like this:

```
new MyInsertDataTask().execute("Your_php_file_path");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: thank's for your answer........i do all posible way, and i also use AsyncTask method. see in my question link--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948014/how-to-convert-single-string-to-jsonarray-in-android

Comment: my problem is that server is more load and then server is suspend.

Comment: then the problem is with your server...find a better server

Comment: i dont know if there is another way because in either way you have to open a connection->send data->close connection. I cannot imagine a different way.

Comment: why do you want to convert string to json array? you can do JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourString);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129734/discussion-between-secret-volcano-and-kostas-drak).

Answer (score 0):

Watch these videos and learn how to insert data into online phpmyadmin server using your android app. For this, get a free web hosting server from 000webhost for creating a database online to store data and then can retrieve data online.

Simple and Interesting way to learn how to store data online on a web server.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3O3CY75ITY

This is the first part of the video.

Comment: Use SQLite for storing offline data.

Comment: **Please clarify exactly what you want.** You want _online_ MySQL server or _offline_, both are implemented separately.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you. I am up-voting your question. Hope somebody will help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129731/discussion-between-secret-volcano-and-harnirvair).